# Create and update Custom Cookie based on multiple GET and POST Values for first time visitors?

Tags: php, plugin-development, variables, cookies

I am not exactly sure the most efficient way to write this code. I collect custom data in my forms and also in my url via get such as:

- Name
- utm_campaign
- URL Referrer
- ID

Among many more. Do I really have to create a setcookie per value or can I run some type of loop to make sure it checks if certain variables exist like above and adds it to a cookie? I understand it might create an issue if I just run the loop for any GET, POST Values but is there a way for me to list values to look for and ignore any values not in that list?

Here is the code I have so far but I am stumped because I need to gather multiple pieces of information, but I think I am going about it the most inefficient way. I plan on tracking the cookie site wide.

I have this in my functions.php file, within a plugin.

```
add_action( 'init', 'setnew_usr_cookie');
function setnew_usr_cookie() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['returning_usr'])) {
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $expire=time()+60*60*24*360;
        $path='/';
        $domain=parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
        setcookie(
            'first_name', 
            $first_name, 
            $expire, 
            $path, 
            $domain
      );
    }
}
```

I didn't know that cookies only hold one piece of information at first which is throwing me off, and I want the cookie to not expire for a year although I know the user might clear it at any time.

Want to set a cookie based only if it is the users first time visiting and the user currently doesn't have a cookie.

Comment: This doesn't seem WordPress specific and is probably better asked at other site of SE network, such as [so].

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that option, the reason I posted here is because I need to make sure the call and overall code is compatible within wordpress.